# Exclude CSS from styles-l/styles-m files if the module output is disabled

Tags: magento2.3, css

I disabled some modules output for my website and would like to exclude their CSS too. Any idea.

Comment: include css files to relavant module xml file.

Comment: Styles are placed in less files by default and merged to one by magento less processor (e.g. vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less). It would be great to add somehow the check if the module output is disabled then exclude _module.less from compilation. IMHO.